# Why nothing is logged when executing parallel code?

Tags: multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I tried to parallelize the following code:

```
def extract_features(dict_w, key, d_f):
    lowess = sm.nonparametric.lowess
    f_v = []
    for c in np.setdiff1d(dict_w[key].columns, ["t", "ts"]):
        dict_w[key][c + "_lowess"] = lowess(
            dict_w[key][c],
            dict_w[key].iloc[:, ~dict_w[key].columns.duplicated()]["ts"],
            is_sorted=True,
            frac=0.05,
        )[:, 1]
        f_v.extend(np.zeros(1,5))

    d_f[key] = np.array(f_v)
```

I tried the following:

```
def extract_features(key, dict_w, shared_dic):
    
    lowess = sm.nonparametric.lowess
    f_v = []
    
    for c in np.setdiff1d(dict_w[key].columns, ["t", "ts"]):
        lw =  lowess(
            dict_w[key][c],
            dict_w[key].iloc[:, ~dict_w[key].columns.duplicated()]["ts"],
            is_sorted=True,
            frac=0.05,)[:, 1]
        #print(lw)
        dict_w[key][c + "_lowess"] = lw
        #print("test ") 
        
        print(lw)
        

    shared_dic[key] = np.array(f_v)
    print(len(shared_dic[key]))


def parallelize(dict_w, max_workers, shared_dic):
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_workers) as pool:
        start = time.perf_counter()
        for key in dict_w.keys():

            pool.submit(extract_features, key, dict_w,  shared_dic)

    logger.info("Execution time (parallel) = {}".format(time.perf_counter() - start))
```

The problem is if I output the first print(lw) I can see the result of the lowess function but if I put the print(lw) after `dict_w[key][c + "_lowess"] = lw` I dont have anything as output in my terminal. Both `dict_w` and `shared_dic` are defined like the following:

```
manager = Manager()
dict_w = manager.dict()
shared_dic = manager.dict()
```

Comment: what did you try and where did you get stuck?

Comment: @Aaron please check what I did.

Comment: Two things: 1. print statements and stdout in general get screwed up by many IDE's. Try it in a system terminal. I can't think of why assigning a value to a container type should alter the value... 2. You may have this covered already, but it's unclear: if you want to assign values to `dict_w` and `shared_dic` in a child process and actually have the updates sent to the main process, you must use some sort of managed dictionary: [multiprocessing managers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#managers) If your shared dictionary is nested, the sub-containers must also be shared

Comment: @Aaron I already defined them through `manager = Manager() and dict_w = manager.dict()`. Similarly for the shared_dic

Comment: it looks like you have nested structures: if any of the containers are not proxy objects (ie a regular dict or list), changes will not propagate to other processes.

Comment: @Aaron you mean I need to change `f_v = []` to be shared

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234382/discussion-between-aaron-and-bib).